# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-6

I've tested my project with development env and everything works fine but after I upload my project to the host I got this error.

```
# log
[2020-02-17T14:54:55.319109 #2097106]  INFO -- : [2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] Started POST "/admin/users" for my_server_ip at 2020-02-17 14:54:55 -0500
[2020-02-17T14:54:55.320555 #2097106] FATAL -- : [2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e]   
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users"):
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e]   
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] rack (2.1.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] /opt/passenger-5.3.7-2.el7.cloudlinux/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] /opt/passenger-5.3.7-2.el7.cloudlinux/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:157:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] /opt/passenger-5.3.7-2.el7.cloudlinux/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] /opt/passenger-5.3.7-2.el7.cloudlinux/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[2ac848c8-15f3-47fd-ad77-ede940b1502e] /opt/passenger-5.3.7-2.el7.cloudlinux/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

here are my routes

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

and here is my form

```
# app/views/admin/users/index.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: admin_user, local: true) do |form| %>

  # my form inputs

  <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-dark' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Output of `$ rails routes`:

```
                           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                      admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                                                                   admin/users#index
                                  POST   /admin/users(.:format)                                                                   admin/users#create
                   new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)                                                               admin/users#new
                  edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                          admin/users#edit
                       admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                                               admin/users#show
                                  PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                                               admin/users#update
                                  PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                                               admin/users#update
                                  DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                                               admin/users#destroy
```

If you are trying to route to this from a form you need to use:

```
<%= form_with(model: [:admin, @user]) do |f| %>
```

See:

- [Controller Namespaces and routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).
- [ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_url)

Comment: sorry @max but my hosting does not provide terminal so I can't run `rails routes` in hosting, but when I run in my local machine I got the same routes, check out the new update I've added the form

Comment: You need to use  ‘form_with(model: [:admin, admin_user])‘ if you want to route to that route. That's clear as day if you look at the linked documentation or try to reproduce this. I would guess the differences between dev and production here are due to bad methodology. You may not be running the same code or your tests are lacking and not catching the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The route you created is under namespace `admin`, but you are making a pos request to`/users`.

Try the same request with `/admin/users`.

Comment: the form action route is requesting `admin/users`, but the error shows only `/users`